# How can I see the scores of every class after run the predict_classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have a classified network for the MNIST dataset (csv) with 10 labels which are numbers (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and after training the network, I run the predict_classes for test_data. I want to know for each of the data in test_set what is the score of every label(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) in y_pred.
for example if predict_classes say that for first data the label is "7" what is the score of 7 and what is the scores of other labels such (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9)
How can I write its code?

```
from keras import models 
import numpy as np
from keras import layers
import tensorflow as  tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, BatchNormalization
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
#Load dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
#normalizing data
x_train = x_train / 255.0
x_test = x_test / 255.0

# bulid model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(15, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True, activation="tanh", unroll=True))
model.add(LSTM(15, dropout=0.2, activation="tanh", unroll=True))
#model.add(LSTM(1, activation='tanh'))
#model.add(LSTM(2, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='tanh' ))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,
             metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))


y_pred = model.predict_classes(x_test)
print(y_pred)
```

Comment: That is what model.predict does.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `model.predict_classes()`, you can use `model.predict()` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict).

This returns an array with the probability for all of the possible classes.